# Is the set $\ell ^2$ a $G_\delta$ in $\mathbb R ^\omega$?

Tags: general-topology, hilbert-spaces

$\ell ^2$ = set of sequences $(x_i)$ of real numbers such that $\|x\|=\sum _{i=0} ^\infty x_i ^2<\infty$.

**Question:** Is $\ell ^2$ a $G_\delta$-set in the product topology $\mathbb R ^\omega$?

I am thinking the answer is no, but I'm not sure.  To prove this, I would presumably suppose $\ell ^2=\bigcap_{n\in\omega}U_n$, where each $U_n$ is open in $\mathbb R ^\omega$, and then consrtuct an element with infinite norm that is in each $U_n$.

**Answer:** Ok, I think I've got a proof (that the answer is no). Please comment to let me know if you think it's alright.

*Proof.* Suppose $\ell ^2=\bigcap_{n\in\omega}U_n$, where each $U_n$ is open in $\mathbb R ^\omega$.

There is a basic open set $B_0$ such that $x_0:=\langle 1,0,0,...\rangle\in B_0\subseteq U_0$. Let $\text{supp}(B_0)$ be the index of the last nontrivial open subset of $\mathbb R$ that generates $B_0$, and let $\sigma_0=x_0\restriction \text{supp}(B_0)+1$. Now take a basic open $B_1$ such that $x_1:=\sigma_0^\frown \langle 1,0,0,...\rangle\in B_1\subseteq U_1$. We may assume $\text{supp}(B_1)>\text{supp}(B_0)$. Let $\sigma_1=x_1\restriction \text{supp}(B_1)+1$. Continuing this process, we construct an infinite sequence $\bigcup _{n\in\omega} \sigma_n$ which is in  every $U_n$, yet it has infinitely many $1$'s, and thus has infinite norm. That's a contradiction. $\square$

That seemed easy, so...

**New Question.** Is $\ell ^2$ first category as a subspace of $\mathbb R ^\omega$?

**Answer:** Yes.

By comparing the usual metrics on $\ell^2$ and $\mathbb R ^\omega$, we can see that the usual topology on $\ell^2$ is finer than its topology as a subspace of $\mathbb R ^\omega$. Thus $F_n:=\{x\in \ell^2:\|x\|\leq n\}$ is closed in $\ell^2$ with the subspace topology. We show each is nowhere dense in $\ell^2$. Consider an open set $U\cap \ell^2$, where $U$ is basic open in $\mathbb R ^\omega$. Let $V=U\cap \pi_j^{-1}[(n,\infty)]$.  If $j>\text{supp}(U)$ then we have $V\neq\varnothing$. Thus $V\cap \ell^2$ is a nonempty open subset of $U\cap \ell^2$, and it misses $F_n$.

This leads to a different proof that $\ell^2$ is not $G_\delta$. For if it were, it would be completely metrizable, as $\mathbb R ^\omega$ is completely metrizable and therefore so is each $G_\delta$ in it. But of course a complete metric space is not first category.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with both proofs. Do note that this subspace called $\ell^2$ is not homeomorphic to $\ell^2$ in its normal topology, based on the norm. The latter *is* completely metrisable (and separable), and as such there is an embedding $i: \ell^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^\omega$, such that $i[\ell^2]$ is a $G_\delta$ in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$. This exercise does show that $i$ is not the identity mapping, essentially.

Comment: oh, that is interesting I hadn't thought about that.   +1!